# Can't find latitude longitude in LG Optimus S

Tags: android, geolocation, latitude-longitude, lg

Hey guys i am building a geolocation application.
The following is the code which i use to get latitude and longitude :-

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
android.location.Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
dataManager.setLatitude(Double.toString(loc.getLatitude()));
Log.d("LATITUDE", dataManager.getLatitude());
```

Well the above code seems to be working on HTC devices and Samsung devices.
But for some strange reason i can not get the latitude and longitude in LG Optimus S.

I am thrown `NullPointerException`

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have both COARSE_LOCATION  and  FINE_LOCATION in my manifest file

Comment: getLastKnownLocation is a bit tricky to deal with. It's not always set by the system. I had some major problems with it being null on my Samsung Galaxy S while working just fine on a Nexus 1. My recommendation is that you catch the NPE and in that case trigger a location update. That way you'll get a location, even if it takes a while.

Comment: you can as well use the google gears to suit your purpose.

Comment: Last time i heard about the google gears was when i was making a web application.. Is it out there also for working on mobile applications as well? i am developing an android application and could you please provide me the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, this is not related to the device type. If you don't have a cell network (e.g. pull out the SIM card), then loc will be null in your code.

Comment: Ya... the phone does have the SIM Card but it is not able to sense the latitude and longitude thought it doesnt give me the error when i make location manager object it gives error when i am printing it in log cat

Comment: Hmm expected: Log.d("This will throw a NPE", null);